# command_line argument

Tags: java, command-line, file, directory

I can not get the difference between these sentences! would you please write some snippet code for these sentences?thanks

- The program will receive a path to a directory as the first command-line argument.
- The program will receive a path to a file as the second command-line argument.

Comment: We have a Path class in JDK 7 but how can make my program to receive a path to a file ?

Comment: What do you mean by "receive a path to a file"? In general, would you please clarify what your problem is (and if this is homework, state the exercise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as that:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // args[0] is the directory path
    // args[1] is the file path
}
```

So what don't you understand?

Comment: what are difference between their codes? e.g. File file = new File(args[0]) this is for directory path,how about the file path?

Comment: The `File` class can represent path names of any type of file (e.g. normal files or directories). The difference is, for a directory, `File(...).list()` will give you a list of contained files. See the documentation at http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a command line copy program that you use like that:

```
copy <destination-dir> <source-file>
```

A simple implementation in Java would be (provided as a fragment):

```
package com.example;
import java.io.File;
public class Copy {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    if (args.length != 2) {
      exitWithErrorCode(); // to be implemented
    }

    File destinationDir = new File(args[0]);
    File sourceFile = new File(args[1]);

    copyFileToDir(sourceFile, destinationDir); 
  }

  private static void copyFileToDir(File sourceFile, File destDir) {
    // to be implemented
  }
}
```

and you would call it like

```
java com.example.Copy /tmp /home/me/example.txt
```

Comment: what does copyFileToDir class would it be?

Answer (score 0):

It means that the program will be run like this:

```
java some.package.YourProgram /some/directory /some/file/name
```